# Latex Citation undefined on input line with biblatex and Overleaf

Tags: biblatex

I am using Overleaf and ref.bib and main.tex are in the same folder.

Reference format:

```
@online{Wolf,
      {author = Wolf Den},
      title = {Eating Grandmas},
      year = {2022},
      url = {https://www.cooking.com},
      }
```

Headers:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,autocite=inline]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref}
```

In text:

```
cuisine.  \parencite{Wolf}
```

I am trying to run the references for Harvard style.

All the citations are coming up as undefined, even after several recompilations of the document. Even `\nocite{*}` is not producing a bibliography. I have tried ref.bib as well as just ref in the relevant header.
The citations themselves are coming up as (**Wolf**) in the text, not (Wolf Den, 2022).

Comment: you need `\addbibresource{ref.bib}` with explicit extension

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure I'd tried that but it's been a long evening of debugging.

Comment: Unrelated, I have never seen using brackets like in a biblatex entry `{author = Wolf Den}`, Is there a special reason for that?

Comment: I agree with @Dr.ManuelKuehner - The field has got to be `author = {Wolf Den},`, not `{author = Wolf Den},`.

Comment: That was a typo after several hours of wrangling LaTeX!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you want to type up a quick answer here? (Which might as well mention the mismatched braces in the `author` field.)

Answer (score 2):

biblatex (unlike bibtex) needs the full filename including extension so

```
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
```

Then once the file is loaded you need to correct the syntax of the `author` field
`{= Wolf Den},`

should be

```
  author = {Wolf Den},
```

Comment: Technically speaking the distinction for the extension is not so much `biblatex` vs BibTeX: It's `\addbibresource` vs. `\bibliography`. `\addbibresource` needs the file extension, `\bibliography` should be used without file extension. `biblatex` supports both `\addbibresource` and `\bibliography` (the latter is deprecated, though). Of course classical BibTeX does not do `\addbibresource`.

Comment: @moewe yes I know (although I never looked at the code details) but at the level of "why does my file not work" I thought the details might not be needed (and you did ask me to answer:-) Incidentally rather than hitting this every few weeks wouldn't it be easier if addbibresource defaulted a .bib extension if one is not supplied and the extensionless file not found?

Comment: Initially the idea was that Biber might support different file types with different extensions, so it had to be given. I think gradually support for other file types was phased out, so we ended up where we are now. I'm generally not too fond of these fallback behaviours. Plus if we wanted to implement it also for BibTeX (where we can't change the search behaviour) we'd have to do this on the LaTeX side.

Comment: @moewe yes I was thinking of doing it on the latex side: \addbibresource (and potentially the core \bibliography) could do similar to includegraphics and handle the extension, adding it for biber and removing it for bibtex

Comment: Mhhh, as I said, I'm really not fond of this kind of fallback behaviour (at least in this context, since the rules are pretty much straightforward). But if you think it is worth discussing, please open an issue at the `biblatex` bugtracker.

Comment: @moewe no it's fine, but if it comes up again within a week or so I may be tempted to open an issue:-)